# fatal error RC1015

Tags: c++, windows

I am really new to programming for `C++` and I was given the task to pick up were a previous employee left off with programming a windows mobile device. I had the emulator working the other week and now when I load the program I get:

> Fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file "xxxx.h"

I have tried almost everything that I have seen on the internet without a single bit of luck. I think that one of my include statements is missing but every time I put one in that works something else breaks. Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the `.rc` file says:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resourceppc.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"
#include "ConnectLoginDlgsRes.h"
#include "AboutDlgRes.h"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resourceppc.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""ConnectLoginDlgsRes.h""\r\n"
    "#include ""AboutDlgRes.h""\r\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#define _AFX_NO_SPLITTER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_OLE_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_TRACKER_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "#define _AFX_NO_PROPERTY_RESOURCES\r\n"
    "\r\n"
    "#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)\r\n"
    "LANGUAGE 9, 1\r\n"
    "#pragma code_page(1252)\r\n"
    "#include ""res\\J3ItemListsppc.rc2""  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources\r\n"
    "#include ""afxres.rc""     // Standard components\r\n"
    "#include ""ConnectLoginDlgs.rc""\r\n"
    "#include ""AboutDlg.rc""\r\n"
    "#endif\r\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDR_MAINFRAME           ICON                    "res\\J3ItemLists.ico"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_J3ITEMLISTS_DIALOG DIALOG  0, 0, 156, 169
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW | 0x80000000L
```

The problem is with the `#include "ConnectLoginDlgsRes.h"` line. The header file is in a shared folder that if it is added that it breaks somewhere else.

Any ideas? Like I said someone else started this and I get to figure it out.

Comment: Your question is way too general without showing us some of your relevant code.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should provide more information so that people can answer your question. For instance, can you include a code snippet where you tried to include "xxxx.h" and the resulting compiler error? At present, you've provided too little information to go on.

Comment: look whether the named file actually exists. If it does look where it is relative to the file that includes it. You may need to add its directory to the to the additional include dirs -- in the 'resource compiler' section. you might have it only added for the C++ compiler.

Comment: Ok I have updated my post sorry for not doing that in the first place

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you program for Windows Mobile we can assume that you use VS2005 or VS2008. You just need to set the search path for the resource compiler.

Lookup the missing file "ConnectLoginDlgsRes.h" and add the path in the project properties dialog. The path must be added in `Configuration Properties`->`Resources`->`General`. Use the "Additional Standard Include Path".

*Edit:*
Since your previous employee might have given you a working project you should also check the build environment. Probably you need some scripts to be executed before you can actually build the VS project.

Comment: Thanks for the help harper. I ended up reinstalling VS2008 and the SDKs and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the resource.h file that is generated in Visual Studio. Make sure you delete the line that includes resource.h from [Solution]->[Project]->Resource Files->app.rc.

In your case this is the line:
'#include "resourceppc.h"'

Answer (score 0):

I solved l error RC1015  using and running the vcvars32.bat file in command line environment which is found in the bin directory under the VC installation directory.or use everything tool to find it. It's limited to setting the appropriate environment variables to enable 32-bit x86 command-line builds. It's the equivalent of the vcvarsall x86 command.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396