# VS Community 2013: cannot open include file 'winres.h'

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I am trying to compile a project, but it looks for includes in the wrong folder or for some other reason cant find `winres.h`.

I tried adding the path to it `(C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um)` everywhere but it doesn't work.

My VC++ include derictories path looks like this: 
`$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include;`

My C/C++ Additional Include Directories path looks like this:
`../../include;../../src/libpocketsphinx;../../../sphinxbase/include;../../../sphinxbase/include/win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

The error is:

```
pocketsphinx.rc(10): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'.
```

How do I change the include path?

Comment: _"I tried adding the path to it everywhere"_ Your level of detail in this question is not really sufficient, is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit added it to VC++ include directories and C/C++ > General > additional include directories.

Answer (score 2):

I would post the images illustrating but I do not have enough reputation points.  To change the includes of a project, follow these steps:

1) Open visual studio.

2) Open your projects.

3) Open the drop down menu by right-clicking your project in the solution explorer.

4) Click on Properties.

Now there are two places to change includes:

1)  Click on VC++ Includes.

2) Add an includes directory to the field "Include Directories".

Or

1) Click on C/C++>General.

2) Add an includes director to the field "Additional Include Directories".

If this is just for the current project, use the second means of adding.  Then of course, click OK or Apply.

For future reference, I suggest going through some of the VS tutorials.  This would be covered there.

Comment: I added the folder to both and nothing changed.

Comment: Added both paths to OP

Comment: pocketsphinx.rc(10): fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'winres.h'.

Comment: I just added the winres.h file into the projects include folder and it still gives the same error. Very confusing

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904529/fatal-error-rc1015), [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d3480ee3-d880-4431-9264-b110a69c8a07/fatal-error-rc1015-cannot-open-include-file-afxresh?forum=Vsexpressvc), or [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/55131/cant-build-the-source-code.html).  Other than that I don't have any other great ideas other than a clean installation, as suggested from one of the linked posts.  Hope you get it figured out and would love to hear what fixes this.